# Не вставляется картинка на сайт на html

Tags: html, linux, html5

пытаюсь вставить фото на сайт, картинка находится в папке images, код в общей папке. Как её вставить? (ОС linux mint)
Пытался images/название, полный путь указывал, но не помогло. Просто на сайте пишется то, что я указал после alt=. Я просто ещё только начинаю, на винде писал - всё было хорошо.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Проект</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <img src="" alt="images/scar.jpeg">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Проект</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <img src="images/scar.jpeg" alt="Описание изображения!">
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Путь к картинке нужно указывать в атрибуте src, вы указали в alt